# Como funciona o PHP Pear?

Tags: php, pear

Gostaria de saber um pouco mais sobre o ***PEAR***:

- Como funciona?
- Como faço para colocá-lo em minha aplicação?
- Qual o destino correto a colocar?
- Informações e detalhes importantes quando estiver utilizando ele?

<sub>**Nota**: Estou utilizando sistema operacional *Windows*.</sub>

Comment: É melhor usar o composer a pear funciona como um repositório de componenetes.

Comment: Um pouco vago demais não acha rray? E o que seria o composer?